# Visual Studio macro to stop sql server and wait for that command to complete before starting the next command

Tags: vba

Hey again. This time my problem lies in trying to move batch files to Visual Studio macros. First off I do not want to call the batch files from the macros. I would like to do the following and have found out how to do it, just not how to make the process wait for the previous command to finish before starting up the next.

1. stop sqlserver
2. stop iis
3. delete cache
4. start iis
5. start sqlserver
6. start application
7. attach to process once the application has fully loaded (having problems on figuring out how to see if the application is up and running).

Above is the english version of what I would like to get done. I can do it all separately through the macros using: **`Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/K net stop mssqlserver")`**, etc

But can't get it to wait until the previous command is done before starting the next one. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Come to find out you can just use && to string together cmd arguments and it will complete them sequentially in order. Worked like a charm.